# Get mangled attribute value of a parent class outside of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

Imagine a parent class which has a mangled attribute, and a child class:

```py
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__is_init = False

    async def init(self):
        # Some custom logic here, not important
        self.__is_init = True


class Bar(Foo):
    ...


# Create class instance.
bar = Bar()
# How access `__is_init` of the parent class from the child instance?
```

How can I get a `__is_init` value from a parent (`Foo`) class?

---

Obviously, I can `bar._Foo__is_init` in this example, but the problem is that class name is dynamic and I need a general purpose solution that will work with any passed class name.

Comment: If you have a reference to the class, you can get its name from its `__name__` attribute. This really sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I see now is iterating over parent classes, and building a mangled attribute name dynamically:

```py
from contextlib import suppress

class MangledAttributeError(Exception):
    ...

def getattr_mangled(object_: object, name: str) -> str:
    for cls_ in getattr(object_, "__mro__", None) or object_.__class__.__mro__:
        with suppress(AttributeError):
            return getattr(object_, f"_{cls_.__name__}{name}")
    raise MangledAttributeError(f"{type(object_).__name__} object has no attribute '{name}'")
```

Checking that this works:

```py
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__is_init = False

    async def init(self):
        self.__is_init = True

class Bar(Foo):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

bar = Bar()
is_init = getattr_mangled(bar, "__is_init")
print(f"is_init: {is_init}")  # Will print `False` which is a correct value in this example
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__is_init = False

    async def init(self):
        self.__is_init = True

class Bar(Foo):

    def getattr_mangled(self, attr:str):
        for i in self.__dict__.keys():
            if attr in i:
                return getattr(self,i)
                # return self.__dict__[i] #or like this



bar = Bar()
print(bar.getattr_mangled('__is_init')) #False
```

if there is a need in `__init__` in Bar we should of course initiate `Foo`'s init too by: `super().__init__()`

When `Foo`'s init is run, self namespace already has attribute name we need in the form we need it (like`_PARENT_CLASS_NAME__attrname`).
And we can just get it from self namespace without even knowing what parent class name is.

Comment: Did you overlook that I use [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)? With name mangling `bar.__is_init` will not work. What will work is `bar._Foo__is_init`, but in a real situation I do not know class name. Perhaps I must detect the parent class name during runtime.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've overlooked. I've changed my answer.